# How to deploy web service through oracle enterprise manager

Tags: java, oracle, service

I have been developing simple web services and clients using JBoss but now I need to deploy a web service in Oracle Enterprise Manager.  I tried deploying a test web service but an axis error shows when I try to access it, saying the axis version number is wrong.

I have also noticed that my web service doesn't show under "Web Services" and only shows under "Applications".  Are there different steps for creating a web service for this Oracle Enterprise Manager?  I tried looking through JDeveloper, since that's what our MiddleWare guy uses, but so far I am still stuck.  When I look at some of the currently deployed web services I see they have an orion-application.xml descriptor, but I don't know what that is used for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I might know this but it has been a while and I no longer have my notes from a previous job.

If it is 9iAS try having a look at link (stack overflow will not let me post it exactly as I am new)
....://download-west.oracle.com/docs/cd/A97329_01/web.902/a95453/orawebservices.htm#1016149

If it is OAS 10g then perhaps Oracle have changed the name (they often confuse me by changing names of software across releases) as they now mention Oracle Web Services Manager at
....://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12524_01/index.htm

Otherwise try searching Metalink for 'axis version' and if that fails raise a Service Request with Oracle.

Sorry not to have the solution but perhaps that will give you a clue.